# Running local JavaScript in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, client, local, microsoft-edge

**Information on Application:**

The application I have is a server/client application that collects data on the client and submits it to the server. All of the UI is hosted at the server, but there is a web server on the client that provides for some data provisioning.

**Problem:**

The client has an icon that can be clicked to access the server. The server can change IPs or hostnames, so we have that stored on the actual client. What we had prior to Microsoft Edge was the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>If you are not redirected to the server within a few seconds, please refresh the page.</p>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $.getJSON('http://localhost:80/svc/settings/server', function(result) {
          window.location.replace("http://" + result.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":80/ui/index.html");
       });
    });
  </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that it can retrieve the address of the server from the local client that the UI is being served to and rewrite the URL to find the UI on the server. However, on Edge, it appears that this Javascript is being ignored.

Is there anyway to get Microsoft Edge to run the local javascript?

UPDATE: After more researching and learning, it appears that the file:// protocol will not allow a redirect. We created a redirect file.

Comment: so did you debug the script and see where it is failing? So is ready being called? Is the json being called? is it success, or is the error callback firing?

Comment: It appears to not being called when we run the file, as if it were being blocked. I will also note that this works in Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Gann14 Do you have *loopback* enabled for localhost access? You can find it in about:flags.

Comment: @Sampson - yes, it is enabled.

Comment: @Gann14 And how are you accessing the resource? Are you using a local server and accessing via localhost:<port>, or are you simply opening the page up over the file:// protocol?

Comment: @Sampson this is a local file using the file:// protocol that makes a call to the local web server.

Comment: @Gann14 I would try firing up a local server instead; there are certain restrictions that place file:// limitations.